# How do I repair the Android-studio launcher icon?

Tags: android, android-studio

my Android Studio was working fine untill I tryed to launch it today.
I have no idea why the launcher icon does not work anymore.

**Android-studio will only launch if I open bin/studio.bat**

I have JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME correctly defined in environment variables.

Im using jdk 7 update 21 x64
Im on windows 7 x64

I have 2 user profiles in Windows
Windows7 and Android

Windows7 was my main profile, it was created when I installed windows 7.
The Android user profile I created specifically for android development.

I installed Android-Studio in userprofile "Android" for ALL users. The strange thing is
**the launcher icon works in my windows 7 user profile.** It points to
C:\Users\Windows7\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

1. Navigate to the folder that contains the android studio data
2. click on "bin" folder
3. Right click on "Studio64.exe"
4. Select "Create Shortcut"
5. Paste it where-ever you want(it can be pasted on the desktop"